# Add "last" and "first" to Wordpress Comment Pagination Links

Tags: php, comments, pagination

```
<?php paginate_comments_links(array('prev_text' => '«', 'next_text' => '»')); ?>
```

Using above in Wordpress theme to add comment pagination links - this displays as

« 1 ... 4 5 6

"1" being the first page of comments and "6" being the last. I'd like to get something like this...

(first) « 1 2 3 » (last)

Answer (score 1):

The number for the first page is always `1`. The number of maximum pages can be set to `$max_page` by calling `get_comment_pages_count()`:

```
 $max_page = get_comment_pages_count();
```

Probably this information helps on how to build links on top of that, which depends a bit on the style of your theme. For building links, I could not find any suitable function in the Worpdress API so far, the most promising seems [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) to me.